# Old SSD filled up, couldn't boot, cannot mount

Tags: boot, partitioning

Plex DB got so big that it entirely filled up my disk.
I rebooted my PC and it wouldn't boot again but get the message: "started session c1 of user gdm" then to c2 or something etc.

Googled it and tried to boot into recovery, got minimal grub bash line.

Got a live linux USB, booted into it. My old ssd (/dev/sdc) was mounted, I could browse it. Unmounted it to check for drive failures. Got the error: bad magic number in super-block.
So I rebooted to get it mounted again and just delete some files to see if that would work.
I cannot mount it anymore.

GParted reads the disk as GPT with an EFI system partition as fat32 and a ext4 partition.

I have a new SSD ready to merge it with, or copy all the data over (cannot be lost, 250GB of metadata and DB is a pain in the ass).
When I try: sudo mount /dev/sdc /media/oldssd I get
"wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdc, missing codepage or helper program or other error".

I'm not that experienced with Linux (and drives) so what would be the next step? I could try to merge my new ssd with my old one but I have no idea if that is a good idea.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please see my answer. Report back. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's check the file system on the old SSD...

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB in “Try Ubuntu” mode
- open a `terminal` window by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
- type `sudo fdisk -l`
- identify the /dev/sdXX device name for your "Linux Filesystem"
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdc2`, replacing `sdXX` with the number you found earlier
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`